# How to put string data from file into integer form for a formula

Tags: python

I'm ranking the top 10 basketball players in the NBA by points, minutes, free throws, and efficiency. All rankings work except efficiency now.

I get an error when I run my function:

```
formula = (player[17] - player[18]) + player[13]))/(player[4]))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:/Users/panda/OneDrive/Desktop/Homework/CS HW 9/pa09.py", line 68, in main
>       effList = efficiency(master_data_list)
>     File "C:/Users/panda/OneDrive/Desktop/Homework/CS HW 9/pa09.py", line 55, in efficiency
>       formula = (((player[6] + player[9] + player[10] + player[11] + player[12])-((player[15] - player[16]) + (player[17] - player[18]) + player[13]))/(player[4]))
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Here's my code:

```
def readData(filename):

    inputFile = open(filename, 'r')

    inputFile.readline()

    master_data_list = []

    for line in inputFile:
        master_data_list.append(line.split(","))

    return master_data_list

def efficiency(master_data_list):

    effList = []

    for player in master_data_list:
        formula = (player[17] - player[18]) + player[13]))/(player[4]))
        index = (player[1], player[2], formula)
        effList.append(formula)

    return effList

def main():

    master_data_list = readData("player_career.csv")

    effList = efficiency(master_data_list)
    effList = sorted(effList, key = lambda x: int(x[2]), reverse = True)

    print("Top 10 players based on total efficiency.")
    for line in effList[:10]:
        print(line[0], line[1]+"-"+line[2])
    print()
```

Here's a sample of the input file:

```
ID  firstname   lastname    leag    gp  minutes pts oreb    dreb    reb asts    stl blk turnover    pf  fga fgm fta ftm tpa tpm
ABDELAL01   Alaa    Abdelnaby   N   256 3200    1465    283 563 846 85  71  69  247 484 1236    620 321 225 3   0
ABDULKA01   Kareem  Abdul-jabbar    N   1560    57446   38387   2975    9394    17440   5660    1160    3189    2527    4657    28307   15837   9304    6712    18  1
```

Comment: You must be trying to subtract strings. Can you reduce that to a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal).

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: I pasted in the data sample and I tried to simplify it so you don't have as much to look at.

Comment: Your example code implies a comma separated fields but your example data is whitespace separated.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each field and make it an `int` if it can be.

Change

```
for line in inputFile:
    master_data_list.append(line.split(","))
```

to

```
for line in inputFile:
    line = line.strip().split(",")
    line = [int(thing) if thing.isdigit() else thing for thing in line]
    master_data_list.append(line)
```

---

The list comprehension can be *expanded* as :

```
row = []
for thing in line:
    if thing.isdigit():
        thing = int(thing)
    row.append(thing)
```

---

If you are sure about the field formats, you know that the first four are strings and the rest are integers:

```
for line in inputFile:
    line = line.strip().split(",")
    line = line[:4] + [int(thing) for thing in line[4:]]
    master_data_list.append(line)
```